# Salesforce Custom URL Button for Docusign & Conga Composer

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, salesforce-lightning

I'm creating a custom salesforce URL button to launch Conga Composer which generates a document to send through Docusign.

The button is working great with the exception of the Opportunity Contact Roles getting mapped to the correct role i.e. Signer vs Carbon Copy.  In the current form, all contacts listed in the contact roles translate to "Signers" in Docusign even though they have a Carbon Copy role in Salesforce.

The code below is formatted with Conga Composer requirements which are slightly different than Docusign's. This isn't the full code but the important pieces for the Contact Roles & Recipients.  I currently have 2 contacts listed in SF's Opp Contact Roles - 1 is a signer & 1 is a Carbon Copy.  They are both coming across as Signers.  In the code below, I also have a person that needs to sign so they are hardcoded as "Signer 2"

```
    /apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer
?serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_370}
&id={!Opportunity.Id}&id={!Opportunity.Id}
    &DocuSignRelatedAccountId={!Opportunity.AccountId}
    &TemplateId=a1234000004CYiDAAW
    &DocuSignVisible=1
    &DocuSignIgnoreOCR=0
    &DocuSignSendReminders=1
    &DocuSignRemindIn=3
    &DocuSignRemindAgainIn=3
    &DocuSignSendAsUserId=00580000003Jfs3AAC
    &DocuSignBrandName=TestCompany
    &DocuSignEndpoint=demo
    &SelectTemplates=1
    &FP0=1
    &DocuSignR2Name=Steve+Tester
    &DocuSignR2Email=steve@testing.com
    &DocuSignR2Role=Signer+2
    &DocuSignR2Type=Signer
    &DocuSignR2RoutingOrder=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a DocuSign template for this?

If you are then you should check the recipient type for each signer in the template is correct.

If the template isn't an issue then you may want to contact conga support for assistance in mapping roles to different signer types